# Restoring a SQL Server 2008 R2 backup on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, backup, restore

I'm getting an error whenever I restore a testing database on SQL Server 2005 that was backed up from SQL Server 2008 R2. It seems that I cannot restore from a higher version of sql onto lower version, how can I solve this?

> The media family on device is incorrectly formed. SQL server cannot process this media family. RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.

I already tested to restore the same file in its own server (SQL Server 2008 R2) and it works, so it's not corrupted.

I cannot install the updated version of SQL into my older server, so how can I use my older SQL Server 2005 as a dev server but with the updated life data from a different instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't restore a 2008 backup on SQL Server 2005. Simply not possible.

You'll need to either:

(a) Restore it on 2008, then use Import/Export wizard, Generate Scripts Wizard, Copy Database Wizard, SSIS, 3rd party tools like SQL Compare, etc. to move the structure and data to the 2005 instance, or

(b) Upgrade. Developer Edition is $50 or so.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So far then the only way that I can make a use of my old server -in my situation is option (A).

Comment: I guess so. What do you mean by "old server"? Like NT 4.0? What is the reason you can't install SQL Server 2008 or higher there?

Comment: No I was referring to a server that we no longer use that has an older version of SQL server 2005. It seems that it takes a while to go through IT so they can get me a copy of the SQL Server 2008, but I may ask them from now as I prefer doing my tests using a different server and not just rely on a testing database on the production machine.

The upgrade is definitely easier than teaching myself SSIS!

Comment: You should match the versions and builds of test and production, unless you're deliberately trying to test a SQL Server upgrade/patch on test before deploying to production.  That way you have a chance of finding any version based differences in testing, rather than the first time you hear of them is when users complain.

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords That's what I'm trying to do actually as soon as we upgraded to make use of the unused older server(HP G2). So IT gave me a copy of the SQL server 2008 r2 finally on a DVD but unfortunately the older server  has only CD drive not DVD. I tried to install it through a shared networked drive, I get an error of: "The image file of ....setup.exe is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine"! no luck upgrading it seems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand any suggestion Aaron on how to install this copy of the SQL Server 2008 r2 into an HP server (second generation) from a networked shared drive but it seems too big? Thanks again.

Comment: @Shayma If the HP can see the networked drive, can't you also copy the media onto the HP's local disks? Also please make sure the media is for 64-bit if the HP is 64-bit. I don't think you would get an error about "machine type" if the installer is "too big" - and I have no idea what exactly would have a problem with the size of the installer anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yea I copied the media files onto the C: drive too from the shared drive on that server (which is a 32 bit server) but  not sure if the folders that I copied from the media is for 64 bit, how can i check that? as viewing the properties for that setup.exe file doesnt help.

Comment: @Shayma My conclusion would be it's 64-bit media, as the error message you're getting is one which you would get running 64-bit media on a 32-bit server. Which incidentally is probably the easiest way to check. Why are you running a 32-bit server in 2014? Why don't you have both flavors of the media?

Comment: @Shamya, if there's not a specific configuration on that old G2 you need, I'd recommend, if your licensing and hardware can handle it, getting a clean install of Windows Server 2008 R2 (which only comes in 64-bit), and then you can do a clean install of SQL Server 2008 R2 as well.  A server that old is probably running 2003 or 2003 R2, and those go out of support in several months, just as XP went out of support a few days ago.

Comment: @AaronBertrand We used to run the 32-bit server (Windows Server 2003 R2 and have SQL Server 2005 instance) up until last October as they gave us now the new 64-bit server that has the the Windows Server 2008 installed and the newer instance of the SQL Server 2008 R2. So I migrated everything for our database to the production server and ran into this problem where I cannot use the old server as a testing environment with current data from backups. I'm asking IT if they can give me the 32-bit media flavor of the SQL server, hopefully its not that big.

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords You are right, it is running the Windoows 2003 R2, and I'm waiting for IT to see if they can install the Windows 2008 R2 on my 32-bit server or give me another media that it is a 32-bit flavor of SQL server 2008 r2 to install. My guess is that they just want us to shutt down and sump the old server but I kept it running for my testings. Thank you all very much for the helpful advices.